# Relation between two expressions of quadrangle skewness

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am using two softwares for the generation of mesh for a CFD problem. Each software has its defintion of skewness for a 2D quadrilateral mesh.
[image]

The first software calculates the skewness based on the following expression:
$$s_1 = \min(\theta_{\text{max}}-90, 90-\theta_{\text{min}})$$

While the second software calculates it based on the following expression:
$$s_2 = \max\left( \dfrac{\theta_{\text{max}} - 90}{90}, \dfrac{90-\theta_{\text{min}}}{90}\right)$$

I am trying to find a link between $s_2$ and $s_1$ so if $s_1$ is known I can easily calculate $s_2$.

In the case where the following relation is statisfied:
$$2\theta_\text{min} + 2\theta_\text{max} = 360$$
Then we get:
$$\theta_\text{max} = 180 - \theta_\text{min}$$
$$s_1 = \min(90-\theta_\text{min},90-\theta_\text{min}) = 90-\theta_\text{min}$$
Therefore:
$$s_2 = \dfrac{s_1}{90}$$
But in the case where the internal angles of the quadrilateral are different $\theta_1 \neq \theta_2 \neq \theta_3 \neq \theta_4$:

[image]

Is it possible to calculate $s_2$ if only $s_1$ is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that $\,\max(a,b)+\min(a,b)=a+b\,$ and  $\,\max(a,b)-\min(a,b)=|a-b|\,$:

- $\;\require{cancel} 90\, s_2 + s_1  = (\bcancel{90}-\theta_{min})+(\theta_{max} - \bcancel{90}) = \theta_{max}-\theta_{min}$
- $\;\require{cancel} 90\, s_2 - s_1  = \big|(90-\theta_{min})-(\theta_{max} - 90)\big|=\big|180-(\theta_{min}+\theta_{max})\big|$

This is insufficient to determine $\,s_2\,$ in general, if you only know $\,s_1\,$ but none of the angles.

If you know $\,\theta_{min} \pm \theta_{max}\,$ then $\,s_2\,$ can be determined from one of the relations above. For example, if $\,\theta_{min}+\theta_{max}=180\,$ then the second equality gives $\,s_2 = \dfrac{1}{90}s_1\,$, as posted.

Comment: where can I find more properties/relations like those two you introduced?

Comment: if $k \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is it always true to say: $\min(ka,kb) = k \min(a,b)$

Comment: @Navaro See for example [useful min/max/abs/sign identities](https://gist.github.com/paniq/3f882c50f1790e323482).